# The name '*' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to open a website in a new window with only a close-button (no back-button, etc). I found the following script, but it is not working, and I am hoping someone can explain why:

```
string WindowOpen = "window.open('Notes.aspx?NoteTableId=" + id + 
                    "&NoteTable=" + Tables.InvoiceHeader + "', 
                    'theWin', 'width=200,height=200,toolbar=0,menubar=0');";
```

When my page loads, though, I get the following errors:

```
The name 'id' does not exist in the current context
The name 'Tables' does not exist in the current context
```

I'm not sure what that means. Can anyone please assist?

Comment: Where is this string created - in the code-behind or on the page? What are id and Tables? Do you have those members defined in a page class?

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're receiving indicate that you haven't defined the variables you are using in the string. The `+` syntax you're using is for String Concatenation. When the compiler sees it, it says "take each of these pieces, convert to String if necessary, and then append them."

Because you haven't defined what `id` is, the compiler is telling you that you need to define it before the computer will be able to convert its value to a string and concatenate it. Same with `Tables`.

It looks like you probably copied this from some other code or article. You might consider whether or not you even need these variables in your own application?

Comment: It's also not even javascript he's copying. It looks like some (bad -- it doesn't escape the variables) C# code that puts javascript into a string (bad pattern to begin with)

Comment: Ok, then probably it's wrong, as I am complete begginer with c#.

Could somebody tell my how to do it?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more detail about what, specifically, you are trying to do? Are you just needing to open a new window?

Comment: Actually, yes. All I need is a new browser window, but not tad.
Would be nice, if it would launch as ''javascript'' window.